# Should I ask my question on SO or on CodeReview?

Tags: support, questions

If I have some existing code which is not buggy (hopefully) and I'm just looking for some design insights about its extension then do I ask on SO or on CodeReview?

I have some rudimentary ideas about the extension but no code yet.

Comment: Did you check the help sections for both? Code Review is only for *working code* that you want to improve. Stack Overflow is usually for *broken code*. Design insights are often better suited to Programmers.SE.

Comment: Doesn't sound right for [so]. If the question is a "whiteboard" question it might be suitable for [programmers.se], but do check their help center first. Code Review (if I understand correctly) is for getting review of code to improve it and its design, rather than extending it, but it may be suitable.

Comment: I've read the FAQ for both but I'm not sure. It is working code but I want to extend it in a way. I have a half-done prototype for it.

Comment: Then that's not a CR question. CR is for 'this is my code, now criticize it', not for 'how can I best extend this'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Code Review would only apply to working code you've already written, not to code that you haven't written yet, or to partial/non-working code.

As it is a ["whiteboard"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/) question, it's probably more appropriate for [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Excellent answer that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Definitely not SO.** - if insights it's what you are looking for - it's off topic.
You need actual code for code review - so it's off topic there too.

I would go with [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) - it will provide you a platform to ask more conceptual questions like design patterns etc.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is an equally good answer compared to the other one.

Comment: @AdamArold - that's a real wonder, I would like to know that too

Comment: The other one also got a downvote. Some people just enjoy downvoting with no reason.

Comment: Well, I upvoted the question and answers, as I agree, they're good and informative.